# How to method-chain `ffill(axis=1)` in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

I would like to fill column `b` of a dataframe with values from `a` in case `b` is `nan`, and I would like to do it in a method chain, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

The following works

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 2, 3, 4], "b": [10, np.nan, np.nan, 40], "c": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]}
)
df["b"] = df[["a", "b"]].ffill(axis=1)["b"]
print(df.to_markdown())

|    |   a |   b | c   |
|---:|----:|----:|:----|
|  0 |   1 |  10 | a   |
|  1 |   2 |   2 | b   |
|  2 |   3 |   3 | c   |
|  3 |   4 |  40 | d   |
```

but is not method-chained. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `df["b"] = df["b"].fillna(df["a"])` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but this is not method-chained (see e.g. https://towardsdatascience.com/using-pandas-method-chaining-to-improve-code-readability-d8517c5626ac), this is assigning values to a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This replaces `NA` in column `df.b` with values from `df.a` using `fillna` instead of `ffill`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = (
    pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4], "b": [10, np.nan, np.nan, 40], "c": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]})
    .assign(b=lambda x: x.b.fillna(df.a))
)
display(df)
df.dtypes
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4], "b": [10, np.nan, np.nan, 40], "c": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]})
df['b'] = df.b.fillna(df.a)
    
|    |   a |   b | c   |
|---:|----:|----:|:----|
|  0 |   1 |  10 | a   |
|  1 |   2 |   2 | b   |
|  2 |   3 |   3 | c   |
|  3 |   4 |  40 | d   |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but this is not what I was looking for. I was looking for a solution that lets me add my modification to a chain, as for example outlined very nicely in this article series (https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1-intro). Your solution requires me to break the chain and assign values to a single column.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I have found is by using the [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.case_when) library:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyjanitor 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 2, 3, 4], "b": [10, np.nan, np.nan, 40], "c": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]}
)
df.case_when(
    lambda x: x["b"].isna(), lambda x: x["a"], lambda x: x["b"], column_name="b"
)
```

Here, the `case_when(...)` can be integrated into a chain of manipulations and we still keep the whole dataframe in the chain.

I wonder how this could be accomplished without `pyjanitor`.